# Accept/Decline/Submit Buttons

Tags: php, html

I created a disclaimer page which includes a Accept/Decline buttons and a Submit button. I would like it so that when someone selects Accept and then Submit it goes to a particular URL1. But if they select Decline it goes to URL2. All the code is below. The current problem is that when I select Accept or Decline then click Submit, it doesn't do anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Warning Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['Accept'])) {
    if ($_POST['Accept'] == 'Accept') {
        $_SESSION['did_accept'] = true;
        header ('Location: http://www.google.com');
        die('<a href="http://www.google.com">Click here to continue</a>');
    } else {
        header ('Location: http://www.yahoo.com');
        die('<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Click here to continue</a>');
    }
}
?>

</head>
<body>
    <p>Some text</p>

    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Accept" id="Accept" onClick="Accept()">
    Accept</label>
    <br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Decline" id="Decline" onClick="Decline()">
    Decline</label>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the question/issue to be addressed?  What doesn't work with what you have now?

Comment: Your radio buttons are named "radio" so they will show up as "radio" in your $_POST array

Comment: I changed them back to name="Accept"

Comment: There a couple problems with your code. You need a `<form action="" method="POST">` around your `input`s. You are using "radio" as the name of the radios so you should check for `$_POST['radio']`, not `$_POST['Accept']`. For example,  `if ($_POST['radio'] == 'Accept')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that I got to work just like I wanted it to based on my original post thanks to all the great advice I received from @Barmar, @McCormick32, @Dezza, and all the others:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Warning Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['Accept'])) {
if ($_POST['Accept'] == 'Accept') {
    $_SESSION['did_accept'] = true;
    header ('Location: https://www.google.com');
    die('<a href="https://www.google.com">Click here to continue</a>');
}
}
if (isset($_POST['Accept'])) {
if ($_POST['Accept'] == 'Decline') {
    $_SESSION['did_accept'] = true;
    header ('Location: http://www.yahoo.com');
    die('<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Click here to continue</a>');
}
}
?>

</head>
<body>
<p>Some text</p>

<form method="post" action="">

<label>
<input type="radio" name="Accept" value="Accept" id="Accept" onClick="Accept()">
Accept</label>
<br>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="Accept" value="Decline" id="Decline" onClick="Decline()">
Decline</label>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: There is one small problem, I just found with the code above. On the webpage it allows you to select Accept and Decline at the same time instead of one or the other. Any ideas why?

Comment: Figured it out. It was because I changed the name of the second radio button. A radio group need to have the same name in order to select one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

To put radio buttons in a group, you have to give them the same name.

```
<label>
<input type="radio" name="Accept" value="Accept" id="Accept">
Accept</label>
<br>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="Accept" value="Decline" id="Decline">
Decline</label>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

You don't need anything in the `formaction` of the button. Just make it `type="submit"` and it will submit to the PHP script in the `action` attribute of the form, which should be the script you showed at the top.

Comment: Something is wrong with my php code. To test, I used google.com for URL1 and yahoo.com for URL2 and the web page goes straight to yahoo every time it loads.

Comment: Does the form use `method="GET"` or `method="POST"`? The code in your PHP assumes it's `GET`.

Comment: Where is the form that the button is supposed to submit?

Comment: You can't use `header()` after outputting HTML. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I modified my answer to give a better example. This is untested but should give you a good idea how it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Warning Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['acceptcheckbox']) && $_POST['acceptcheckbox'] == 'Yes') {
$_SESSION['did_accept'] = true;
header ('Location: http://www.google.com');
die('<a href="http://www.google.com">Click here to continue</a>');
}
if (isset($_POST['declinecheckbox']) && $_POST['declinecheckbox'] == 'Yes') {
header ('Location: http://www.yahoo.com');
die('<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Click here to continue</a>');
}
?>

</head>
<body>
<p>Some text</p>

<form action="" method="POST" id="myForm">
<input type="checkbox" name="accept" id="acceptcheckbox" style="display: none" value="Yes">
<input type="checkbox" name="decline" id="declinecheckbox" style="display: none" value="Yes">
<label>
<input type="button" name="acceptbutton" value="Accept" id="Accept" onclick="CheckAccept()">
Accept</label>
<br>
<label>
<input type="button" name="declinebutton" value="Decline" id="Decline" onclick="CheckDecline()">
Decline</label>
</form>
</body>

<script>
function CheckAccept(){
document.getElementById("acceptcheckbox").checked = true;
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
function CheckDecline(){
document.getElementById("declinecheckbox").checked = true;
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Where would I add the URL's for Accept and Decline?

Comment: It would be the same as you have it now, except instead of your PHP page looking for a GET variable it will be looking for a POST variable and the Accept / Decline checkbox value.

Comment: You need to put your HTML buttons in a form with method="POST". This will send the elements to the page via a POST request.

Comment: I just updated the javascript and tested it to ensure it works; however, the PHP I could not test at the moment but should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

```
if (isset($_POST['Accept']) && $_POST['Accept'] == 'Accept') {
    $_SESSION['did_accept'] = true;
    header ('Location: http://www.google.com');
    die('<a href="http://www.google.com">Click here to continue</a>');
} else {
    header ('Location: http://www.yahoo.com');
    die('<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Click here to continue</a>');
}
```

As `$_POST['Accept']` is not set on the first page load, as it is a GET request and not a POST request, you go to the `else` block which immediately redirects you.

Try something like this instead:

```
if (isset($_POST['Accept'])) {
    if ($_POST['Accept'] == 'Accept') {
        $_SESSION['did_accept'] = true;
        header ('Location: http://www.google.com');
        die('<a href="http://www.google.com">Click here to continue</a>');
    } else {
        header ('Location: http://www.yahoo.com');
        die('<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Click here to continue</a>');
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed the issue of it going straight to yahoo.com, thanks. But now, when I select Accept/Decline and then Submit it doesn't do anything but I'm guessing that has to do with what Barmar and McCormick are talking about not having a form as part of my code.?.?

Comment: Yes, that is because you need a `<form>` so that the browser knows what to send, how to send it, and where to send it. See @Barmar and @McCormick32 for answers to that question